# script management using rabbitmq python

Tags: python, scripting, rabbitmq, pika

we use rabbitmq to manage script framework. we have more than 20 customers and per customer we run about 15 scripts 6 to 7 times a day through cron jobs. we have configured in such a way that maximum 5 threads will spawned per worker. we have three machines and each machine run about 3 workers. problem here is some scripts taking time because of lot of data volume for some customers. Because of that, lot of messages are queued up.

how better we can manage this kind of problem?
Is there any tool which solves these problem of job scheduling without job getting delayed? 
how to ensure that, all scripts running without getting missed?

if any other information required, please ask in comments

Comment: Have you tried Celery? It is considered best for this type of work. http://www.celeryproject.org/

Comment: I tried prototyping this using celery. but how well celery handle execution of scripts without failure? it also depends on either rabbitmq, redis for message delivery right?

Comment: Yes, it will use Rabbitmq or Celery for queue management. But using celery it will be easy for you to create multiple queues, control concurrency etc. Like you can create a queue per task type. And then run 20 workers (for 20 customers) on 3 machines monitoring that task's queue. In that way one task can be run concurrently for all the customers. And so on there may be many options according to your task structure.